# Multiview 3D reconstruction

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I tried to do 3D reconstruction of multiple views by using multiview essential matrices to construct 3D view of each image view of object. However, I am shocked that the 3D points I found are all on about XY plane. I guess that it maybe regarding to the large value of essential matrix or weird number of projection matrix estimated. What are the suggestions for me to compute precise 3D points coordinate?

Comment: What is a "multiview essential matrix"?  Are your cameras calibrated? Have you tried to do reconstruction from 2 views?

Comment: multiview essential matrix is essential matrix for each 2 view images of N views image, remind me if wrong name. My camera is a single camera with calibrated. I tried reconstruction from 2 view but the coordinate calculated are weird.

Comment: I would suggest that you first make the reconstruction from 2 views work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Computer Vision System Toolbox, this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html#zmw57dd0e9002) may be helpful.